# ng-grid is not displaying any data

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have been trying to display the json data in the ng-grid since 3 hrs but could not do it.I have followed as per the instructions given in the Getting started guide of ng -grid.But could not display the data in the grid.

In my UserEdit.aspx page my HTML code is as follows:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserEdit.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleWebApp.UserEdit" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html >
        <head runat="server">
            <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/ng-grid-2.0.14.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/Control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/ng-grid.min.css" />
            <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Styles/Style.css"/>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server" novalidate>
            <div ng-app="myApp">
                <table style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                    <tr style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;width:100%">
                        <td style="width:50%;text-align:left">
                            First Name:
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="FirstName"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50%;text-align:left">
                            Last Name:
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="LastName"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>
           <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

In my Control.js file for the module i have injected the dependency of ngGrid and in my controller `MyCtrl` I initialize gridoptions variable.My js code is as follows

In my Control.js it is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngGrid"]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
                 { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
                 { name: "Jacob", age: 27 },
                 { name: "Nephi", age: 29 },
                 { name: "Enos", age: 34}];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
     data:'myData'
     };
 $scope.$apply();
});
```

FYI ,There are no errors that appear in console.And when i view the example given in [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/](http://This%20Website) , and if i view the code in the plunker the same thing happens(i.e I cannot see any grid ).

Appreciate any Help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `MyCtrl`  outside of `ng-app`

It should be inside of it's module.

try like this

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 </div>
</div>
```

N:B : you don't need `$scope.$apply();` .

Comment: When i removed $scope.$apply() it worked.May I know Why??

Comment: $apply will make digest process run again but if it's already running then it'll throw error. that is happening in you case @BhanuChowdary

Comment: you can learn more from here : http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

Comment: Ok.Thank you very much for saving a couple of hours.

Comment: @BhanuChowdary well that's upvote. in order to mark it accepted thare is a check sign below down vote icon